# Menu with FlowScope Items in JSF Template

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following menu where all menuItem are starting different views that use FlowScope.

In my home page ex: "http://localhost:8080/abc" I can Start any flow from the MenuItem. But when I get into one flow, I get the error:  **Could not resolve NavigationCase for outcome: view-all**

If I change from outcome to action in the menuItem, I can get into the view, but if I try to start another follow I cant.

Here is my menu :

```
<h:body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            <ui:insert name="header">
                <h:form>
                    <p:menubar id="menu">
                <p:menuitem>
                    <h:link>
                        <h:graphicImage name="fme.png" height="50" />
                    </h:link>
                </p:menuitem>
                <p:submenu label="Colaborador" icon="ui-icon-document">
                    <p:menuitem value="Criar Colaborador" action="create-colaborator" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Editar Colaborador" action="create-colaborator" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Listar Todos" action="view-all" />
                </p:submenu>
                <p:submenu label="Relatorio" icon="ui-icon-document">
                    <p:menuitem value="Relatorio" action="exportar-relatorio" />
                </p:submenu>

                <p:menuitem style="margin-right:600px">
                    <h:link>
                        <h:graphicImage name="swiss.png" height="40" />
                    </h:link>
                </p:menuitem>
            </p:menubar>

                </h:form>
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div id="contentWrap" class="ui-fluid">
            <div id="content">
                <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <ui:insert name="footer">
                Um produto de FME em parceria com a SwissContact. 
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:body>
```